# Prototype (Javascript): How do I observe multiple events for the same element?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Veeery basic question, but I haven't been able to find a simple answer (and I have no idea what I'm doing and no time to properly learn javascript or prototype at the moment :-/).

I'm trying to re-use [this bit of code](http://www.andrewsellick.com/67/simple-javascript-idle-state-using-prototype) and it would even do exactly what I want ;), except that I don't know how to change this part:

```
function init() {

    Event.observe(document.body, 'mousemove', resetIdle, true);

    setIdle();

}
```

I'd like it to observe not only 'mousemove', but also 'keydown' at the same time. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function init() {

    Event.observe(document.body, 'mousemove', resetIdle, true);
    Event.observe(document.body, 'keydown', resetIdle, true);

    setIdle();

}
```

It's obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah it is kind of obvious ;) But when I tested that before asking the question, it didn't seem to work... i.e. it only seemed to observe 'mousemove', but not 'keydown'. And so now I'm wondering what on earth I did wrong the first time round cause I didn't get any errors in the console and yet it seems to be working now :] Go figure...

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else. BTW that code looks strange.

Comment: By the way that's not how the official docs show it! THIS here is much much much much better.

Answer (score 1):

On the chance that you only want to reset the timer when moving the mouse and holding a key at the same time you'll need to update this function:

```
function resetIdle(event){

    if (event.altKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey) {
        window.clearTimeout( timeOut );
        setIdle();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, not what I was after, but cool to know nonetheless :)

Comment: It was a long shot but the question could have meant that. Maybe someone else will find it useful.